# Gradle task dependency not executed on subprojects

Tags: gradle

Scenario:

```
Root project
      |- Project1
```

Both, root project and project1 have a task named `b`.
Root project has a task named `a`, that depends on `b`.
When I call `gradle a` the task `b` is executed only in root project. It is not executed in project1.

Is this an issue or is it like this by-design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an issue. Though this tasks have a same name, they are different. It's just like a two variables with the same name in different classes. If you make your task dependencies, as:

```
taskA.dependsOn taskB
```

It make a dependencies between the tasks of the same project. If you need to provide a dependency to subproject's task, you have first to point, which project contains this task, like:

```
taskA.dependsOn ':subprojectName:taskB'
```

You may find usefull to read the official documentation about it [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:dependencies_which_dependencies)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't see that part of documentation.

Comment: It's not clear from the answer (or the documentation), how to do this gracefully. Yes, in the example, there is only 1 subproject. But what if I have 10? I want to call the 'build' task on all of the subprojects... how would I go about doing so? Will dependsOn handle this or do I have to iterate?